# /etc/udev/rules.d/ vs /lib/udev/rules.d/ - which to use and why?

Tags: udev, etc

The Arch wiki [recommended](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gamepad#Steam_Controller_not_pairing) creating a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` to fix my Steam controller issues. This worked! However, I noticed that there are no other rules in this folder except for the one I just created. Additionally, all other sources I've seen say to place udev rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/`, and there are plenty of other udev rules in this folder too. Why are there two folders for seemingly the same thing, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The difference between the two folders is that:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d
```

Contains default rules files. Do not edit these files.

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules
```

Contains customized rules files. You can modify these files or create them.

However, files with identical file names replace each other. Files in `/etc` have the highest priority and take precedence over files with the same name in `/lib`. This can be used to override the default rules.

Another thing, to disable the the rules file entirely, you can create a symlink in `/etc` with the same name as a rules file in `/lib`, pointing to `/dev/null`.

So to finish, Udev rules written by the administrator go in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, and their file name has to end with `.rules`. The default udev rules  are found in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` (or `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d`). If there are two files by the same name under `/lib` and `/etc`, the ones in `/etc` take precedence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm not sure why I have been downvoted for asking a question? :(

Comment: @AaronFranke you have been downvoted because them downvote fairies were having a bad day.